# How can I unmarshall a 3rd party data structure into a object

Tags: ruby, unmarshalling

I'm looking to unmarshall a 3rd party data structure into a ruby object, so I can print a prettified version of the structure.

I know the layout of the data structure, but I can't seem to find a good way to read the data into a ruby structure. I looked at using `String#unpack`, but it requires me to remember all the previous offset for each unpack call, which is unfortunate.

Is there a good alternative, or a de-facto way of using readByte/Short/Int calls to read data into a structure?

Comment: Is the 3rd party object saved in YAML or JSON format?

Comment: In any case try this https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby

Comment: No, it's a custom binary format

Comment: We need a sample input and sample output, and an example of your code. [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-unpack) can return an array based on the `format` string given to it. That'd be your source for converting a binary string into something else. But without example input, output and code we can't really tell what you're doing.

Comment: No, you don't. This is a general question on how to handle unpacking binary structs in Ruby. Such questions have answers for C#, Java and C++. And I asked for a alternative to unpack, or pointers to how it can be used with dynamic offsets.

Comment: Then how is your question not answered by the `unpack` documentation which has examples showing how to parse a binary string into its component fields? `unpack` doesn't require remembering offsets, unless you want to use them. It'll walk through the data given the right format.

Comment: Because, as mentioned in the question, unpack requires you to know all offsets up front. This doesn't work. Plus, I was hoping there was a more sane way to do it, hence asking a question in the first place. Why even bother with the question, if all you can suggest is to do what I wrote I already tried in the question itself?

Comment: We are trying to help you, but you haven't told us enough to decipher the input. Binary input can be structured in many different ways. It can have fixed length or variable-length fields using length bytes or terminating bytes. It can have encoded values, it can have bit-fields, and without a better idea what you're looking at it's difficult to say what to use.

Comment: Yes, and so far nobody have suggested a different way to unmarshall binary input, aside from `String#unpack`, despite me asking for exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at https://github.com/dmendel/bindata
It will get the job done but is slower than just unpacking. If you have a lot of data and/or speed of deserialization is key go for the unpack.

Comment: Not accepting for the library, but the documentation of bindata gives examples how to do it in pure ruby as well, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen: But it uses `String#unpack`?

Answer (score 1):

In my past I've had to tear apart MP3, image files, etc. using C, Perl, and Ruby. Those data streams can contain fixed-length and variable length fields. Some fields are at known offsets from the start or end of the data. Some fields don't even have to exist and you have to dig into the data to determine whether they are there based on heuristics.

Fixed-length records are easy, and you'll get those from database outputs where they're maintaining field sizes, or from encoded data.

Sometimes an incremental parsing has to be done, where you grab what you know, then you sum the sizes of what you've parsed to that point, and use that as an offset to grab the next field, and iteratively walk through the structure.

It's difficult for us to say what the ideal way to process the data is without sample input or a knowledge of what the file format is.

While it's possible to do using accessors or methods that mask what is going on underneath everything, odds are good that `unpack` or a `scanf`-type method is the core method being used. Both are still field/data-type oriented and require advance knowledge of the format/fields.